# What is this function call syntax?

Tags: c++

I am using the [cxxopts](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts.git) library and came across this syntax which compiles fine on my machine, but never saw anything like it. Can someone explain?

```
 cxxopts::Options options("Hello World", "Argument parsing test");
 options.add_options()
    ("o, obj", "Object File", cxxopts::value<std::string>())         
    ("t, tex", "Texture File", cxxopts::value<std::string>())
    ;
```

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, they are similar but not duplicates since [cxxopts](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts) appears to be an unrelated to boost.

Comment: @RSahu Maybe different libraries, but both apply exactly the same 'trick'...